# Specifying @Produces wildcard handling in JAX-RS

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs

Assume a class:

```
public class MyResource {

    @Path("/thing")
    public String getThing() {
        // returns HTML
    }

    @Path("/thing")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getThingJSON() {
        // returns JSON
    }
}
```

How can I have requests with a header of `Accept: */*` be handled by `getThing()`? At the moment having a wildcard accept header results in `getThingJSON()` getting called. If I have an accept header of `Accept: text/html` then `getThing()` gets called.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue, where I have to methods with a specific `@Produces()` annotations. This trick works:

```java
@Path("/thing")
public String getThing() {}

@Path("/thing")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "*/*;q=0"})
public String getThingJSON() {}
```

When using MIME types, you can add the q property, which indicates priority (0 to 1). The absence of the q property implies 1, but apparently the q=0 tricks Jersey to use the other function.

It's kind of a hack, so I don't know if it will remain working, but helped me out.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `a @Produces({MediaType.WILDCARD})`

to getThing()

Comment: The spec says: "In the absence of either of these annotations, support for any media type (“*/*”) is assumed." and testing confirms this.

Comment: Have you tried debugging all the way through to see which of the rules is being hit upon?